# Google cloud vision subnet

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-vision, vision

I need to know google subnet to test cloud vision on my test environment. Need to open access to those IP block. I couldn't find any resources, can anyone help me please?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Connectivity Tests diagnostics [tool](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/concepts/overview), that lets you check connectivity between network endpoints. It help you to analyzes your configuration If you are running Google managed services, also you can use it  to analyse routes to and from Google-managed services.
Also in the Google cloud shell you can type this command to get the subnet that are usables in your default project.

```
gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable
```